# Can't find System.Convert in .Net 5 Core beta2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We recently upgraded our MVC 6 project to the beta2 and .Net Core is complaining that it cannot use System.Convert.  Can someone tell me where this has been moved?

[image: Error Example]

My project JSON contains the following for Core:

```
"aspnetcore50": {
    "dependencies": {
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-22416",
        "System.Threading.Tasks": "4.0.10-beta-22416",
        "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0-beta-22416",
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.6.0",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-22416"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the unofficial [package search website](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/) to see in which package a certain API is.

`System.Convert` is in `System.Runtime.Extensions` if you are are using CoreCLR (aspnetcore50)

Comment: hi victor, can you point me where I can find changes like this in GitHub. I think is incorrect to ask a question when you are doing changes like this instead of looking at the documentation

Comment: Son_of_Sam you wouldn't look in github, you would use the link Victor provided.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet is a good place to start. There is no really easy way to discover the changes unless you keep an eye on each commit